# Using System.Text.Json as Default Serializer in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-2.1

For my particular .NET Core 2.1 application, I've benchmarked that System.Text.Json performs much better than Newtonsoft. I know it's the default in .NET Core 3.x, but I can't upgrade to that quite yet.

In individual endpoints, I'm able to serialize using System.Text.Json no problem

```
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, options);
```

But it's not clear to me how I would do that as a default for the entire application. If I were to adjust JsonOptions in `Startup.cs`, the `SerializerSettings` object is a part of Newtonsoft.

```
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings...
});
```

Is there a way to change the default Json serializer for a .NET Core 2.1 app?

Comment: I suppose you could make a custom formatter for `System.Text.Json` in ASP.NET Core 2.1, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-2.1. The source code for `JsonOutputFormatter` in asp.net 2.1 is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v2.1.21/src/Mvc/Mvc.Formatters.Json/src/JsonOutputFormatter.cs) so you could use that as a model.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can try using a custom implementation of input/output formatters.

There's an example using protobuf to handle serializtion.
https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/september/custom-input-and-output-serializers-in-aspnet-core/

I think you'll be most interested in reviewing the official MSDN documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-2.1

```cs
   public class JsonInputFormatter : TextInputFormatter, IInputFormatterExceptionPolicy
    {
        public InputFormatterExceptionPolicy ExceptionPolicy { get; }

        public JsonInputFormatter()
        {
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));

            SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
            SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.Unicode);
        }

        public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
        {
            string request = null;
            using(var sr = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body))
            {
                request = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(request, context.ModelType);
            return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Indeed, no issue installing the package. The issue is how I would utilize that as the default Json Serializer in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application. How to alter Startup.cs to start using this rather than Newtonsoft

Comment: Oops, missed that part.  I thought your question was how to use System.Text.Json in 2.1...I will update my answer shortly.